# Would very high energy density (like in Back holes) give a non-zero value to inflation field?

Tags: energy, black-holes, cosmological-inflation

I have been watching some PBS SpaceTime about inflation, and it is explained that there is an inflation field that at high energy density makes space expand, it then fell into a false vacuum state, and then later fell into "the path" to actual zero-state.
Then when the inflation field value dropped to a certain level that field gets converted to matter and energy as we know and that is essentially where we got our observable universe.

Black holes are very energy-dense, wouldn't it mean that at a certain energy density inflation field would get a non-zero value again and start expanding again, or I am mixing two completely different things, and once the inflation field gets to zero state it is only one way and inflation cannot be restarted.